# C# server that supports IPv6 and IPv4 on the same port

Tags: c#, ipv6, ipv4

Is it possible to have a Socket that listens and accepts both IPv6 and IPv4 clients? I used a IPv6 socket in C# hoping that it would automatically be backwards compatible but IPv4 clients cause an invalid ip address exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=ipv6+and+ipv4+on+the+same+TCP+port&source=bl&ots=Kq5xPnhmPn&sig=OUz1Ta3wwSaXzmwCfK7Qgt_pSNA&hl=en&ei=gcWISpmpEoGHkQXO4uSaBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false). You can accept IPv4 clients as well as IPv6 clients [with the one server socket](https://web.archive.org/web/20130909044601/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/11/18/494769.aspx).

Comment: silky: I'd say you're right. I've totally rewritten my answer.

Comment: Looks like one of your links may have evaporated.

Answer (score 7):

Set the socket's `IPv6Only` option to `false`:

```
Socket MySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
MySocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
```

(taken from Matthew Iselin's second link)