# Use UdpClient with IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: c#, networking, ipv6, ipv4, udpclient

A little while ago I created a class to deal with my LAN networking programs.  I recently upgraded one of my laptops to windows 7 and relized that windows 7 (or at least the way I have it set up) only supports IPv6, but my desktop is still back in the Windows xp days, and only uses IPv4.  The class I created uses the UdpClient class, and is currently setup to only work with IPv4..  Is there a way to modify my code to allow sending and receiving of IPv6 and IPv4 packets??
It would be hard to scrap the classes code, a lot of my programs rely on this class.  I would like to keep the class as close to its original state, so I don't need to modify my older programs, only switch out the old class for the updated one.

Thanks for any and all help,
Max

Send:

```
    using System.Net.Sockets;UdpClient tub = new UdpClient ();
    tub.Connect ( new IPEndPoint ( ToIP, ToPort ) );
    UdpState s = new UdpState ();
    s.client = tub;
    s.endpoint = new IPEndPoint ( ToIP, ToPort );

    tub.BeginSend ( data, data.Length, new AsyncCallback ( SendCallBack ),s);

    private void SendCallBack ( IAsyncResult result )
    {
        UdpClient client = (UdpClient)( (UdpState)( result.AsyncState ) ).client;
        IPEndPoint endpoint = (IPEndPoint)( (UdpState)( result.AsyncState ) ).endpoint;
        client.EndSend ( result );
    }
```

Receive:

```
    UdpClient tub = new UdpClient (ReceivePort);

    UdpState s = new UdpState ();
    s.client = tub;
    s.endpoint = new IPEndPoint ( ReceiveIP, ReceivePort );
    s.callback = cb;
    tub.BeginReceive ( new AsyncCallback ( receivedPacket ), s );

    public void receivedPacket (IAsyncResult result)
    {
        UdpClient client = (UdpClient)( (UdpState)( result.AsyncState ) ).client;
        IPEndPoint endpoint = (IPEndPoint)( (UdpState)( result.AsyncState ) ).endpoint;
        Byte[] receiveBytes = client.EndReceive ( result, ref endpoint );
        Packet ThePacket = new Packet ( receiveBytes );
        client.Close();
        //Do what ever with the 'ThePacket' now
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you: [C# server that supports IPv6 and IPv4 on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285953/c-server-that-supports-ipv6-and-ipv4-on-the-same-port)

Comment: That answer also contains a link to http://blogs.msdn.com/malarch/archive/2005/11/18/494769.aspx which sort of does exactly what you want -- it starts a socket that can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

Answer (score 1):

**UdpClient** constructors without port don't bind socket immediately. Also **UpdClient** exposes its socket. This combined allows to modify socket options before binding.

Receiver:

```
using var receiver = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
receiver.Client.DualMode = true; // enables both IPv4 and IPv6
receiver.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 15621));

var incData = await receiver.ReceiveAsync();
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(incData.Buffer));
```

Run it and check that it is listening both `0.0.0.0` and `[::]`

```
PS C:\> netstat -an | findstr 15621
  UDP    0.0.0.0:15621          *:*
  UDP    [::]:15621             *:*
```

Sender:

```
using var sender = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
sender.Client.DualMode = true;
sender.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback, 15621));
await sender.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello server"));
```

Answer (score 0):

UdpClient can be prepared to receive on both IPv4 and IPv6 by providing a DualMode socket:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234));
var udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Client = socket;
... (use udpClient)
```

Sending is easier, we can create UdpClient with the specified target address (IPv4 or IPv6). AddressFamily can be provided in the constructor, if needed.

Comment: You have to use var udpClient = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6); instead of the default constructor. Otherwise an invalid Argument Exception "The AddressFamily InterNetworkV6 is not valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint" is rised when trying to receive data because UdpClient does not change its private Address Family when setting a new Socket.